# Solution of partial differential equation including integral equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, definite-integrals

Let $u(x,t)$ be a solution of the heat equation $\displaystyle \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}$ in the rectangle $[0,\pi]\times [0,T]$ subject to the boundary condition $u(0,t)=u(\pi,t)=0$ , $0\le t\le T$ and the initial condition $u(x,0)=\phi(x)$, $0\le x\le \pi$. If $f(x)=u(x,T)$ then which of the following is true for a suitable kernel $k(x,y)$ ?

(A) $\displaystyle \int_0^\pi k(x,y)\phi(y)\,dy=f(x)$.

(B) $\displaystyle \phi(x)+\int_0^\pi k(x,y)\phi(y)\,dy=f(x)$.

(C) $\displaystyle \int_0^xk(x,y)\phi(y)\,dy=f(x)$.

(D) $\displaystyle \phi(x)+\int_0^x k(x,y)\phi(y)\,dy=f(x)$.

I have no idea where to start. I can solve the PDE by separation of variable method, but I believe that does not help to solve this kind of problem. Any help please.

Comment: Well, what do you get if you take the solution $u(x,t)$ found by separation of variables, and put $t=T$? Try to match that expression against the given options.

Comment: @HansLundmark Solving by separation of variable and using the boundary conditions finally we get, $f(x)=e^{-k^2T}\phi(x)$, where $k$ is a constant. Now, I am unable to match the option. Can you please help me at this step ?

Comment: Separation of variables isn't enough to solve a PDE. It finds you a certain very useful set of solutions, which you then use to build your full solution. If there's some section of your text that derives a heat kernel, I'd suggest rereading that carefully.

Comment: That's not the correct formula for $f(x)$. From separation of variables together with the boundary conditions, you should get that $u_k(x,t) = e^{-k^2 t} \sin(kx)$ is a solution for every integer $k \ge 1$, and then you need to find the constants $c_k$ such that $u(x,t) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty c_k u_k(x,t)$ satisfies the initial condition, and *then* (but not earlier) you should be able to put $t=T$ and match against the given options.